# webapps folder in Tomcat9 - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat9

I've just installed tomcat9 in ubuntu, upload a war using the  manager webapp , but I am not able to locate the webapps folder in the system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default directory is `/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/`. You only need to remember `/var/lib/tomcat9/`, the other interesting directories like `conf` and `logs` are symlinked from there.